# Зачем функция time() C/C++ принимает аргумент?

Tags: c++, время

Как я прочитал на [cppstudio](http://cppstudio.com/post/597/), функция `time()` при передаче ей аргумента, не равного `NULL`, возвращает то же значение, на которое указывает аргумент.

Вопрос: в чём вообще смысл аргумента этой функции, если она, по сути, выполняет с ним разыменование указателя? Я верю, что здесь есть скрытый смысл, но пока что мне представляется, что лучше было бы сделать эту функцию не принимающей аргументов, чтобы она просто возвращала значение текущего времени. Переубедите меня в том, что передавать ей аргумент кроме `NULL` бесполезно (можно ведь просто разыменовать указатель с помощью `*`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Как я прочитал на cppstudio, функция time() при передаче ей аргумента, не равного NULL, возвращает то же значение, на которое указывает аргумент.

Она не возвращает то же значение. Ниже приведена POSIX-реализация функции time:

```
time_t
time (time_t *t)
{
  struct timeval tv;
  time_t result;
  if (__gettimeofday (&tv, (struct timezone *) NULL))
    result = (time_t) -1;
  else
    result = (time_t) tv.tv_sec;
  if (t != NULL)
    *t = result;
  return result;
}
```

Как видите, она не возвращает то же значение - она *дублирует* результат.

> Вопрос: в чём вообще смысл аргумента этой функции

Возможно, в первых реализациях под Unix, эта функция возвращала X в случае успеха и `errno` в случае ошибки.

Comment: Да, Вы правы. В cppstudio ошибка. Тогда всё встаёт на свои места, спасибо.

Comment: @V-Mor, рад помочь!

Answer (score 3):

Вероятнее всего потому что это функция из С, а в нём есть принцип возврата кода ошибки функции. В случае неудачи он вернёт -1, и если надо проверить, то просто сделать:

```
time_t __val;
if (time(&__val) == -1)
{
  perror ("Time error");
}
```

Comment: Ну не знаю. С тем же успехом можно было бы сделать `(__val = time()) == -1`.

Comment: Интересно, кто-нибудь в здравом уме, проверяет результат `time()` на -1?

Comment: Не считаю это логичным объяснением. Как написал @HolyBlackCat, код ошибки можно возвратить и без аргументов.

Comment: Только тут 2 ситуации, предположим, у вас в __val уже есть значение, в вашем случае, он его перезапишет, в случае, если передать, как параметр, то он не изменится. И да, люди в здравом уме делают проверки. Это большая ошибка не проверять коды возврата.

Comment: @Inquisitions, если передать параметр, то он как раз таки изменится.

Comment: @Inquisitions, вы в самом деле считаете, что программисту на **user level** выдаться шанс увидеть `time(0) == -1`?

Answer (score 3):

Функция [time_t time(time_t *tloc)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/time.2.html) возвращает *время в секундах* (прошедшее с 01.01.1970 г.) и помещает *его же* в память по передаваемому ей указателю (адресу памяти).

Теперь об ее интерфейсе (почему он такой). Вкратце, конечно, это старое наследство, доставшееся от первых версий Unix.

Ее интерфейс в общем виде совпадает с интерфейсом устаревшей функции [int ftime(struct timeb *tp)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ftime.3.html), которая заполняла вот такую структуру:

```
struct timeb {
       time_t         time;
       unsigned short millitm;
       short          timezone;
       short          dstflag;
};
```

и возвращала 0 при успешном вызове и -1 при ошибке
(кстати, в то время, когда в программах еще использовалась `ftime()`, функция `time()` возвращала время в 32-bit типе `long`, а типа `time_t` тогда еще не было).

В первом широко распространенном руководстве [Stephen R. Bourne. The Unix System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Unix_System) написано, что `time()` и `ftime()` это две точки входа в общую функцию, что объясняет сходство их интерфейсов.

Такая вот, история развития системы.